# Why I can't transfer data to a nested property in a view model using automapper?

Tags: c#, automapper, asp.net-core-2.0

I am trying to transfer my data from my entity model (`PatientRegistry`) to a view model (`PatientRegistryViewModel`) and the latter has only one simple nested property (`MobilePhoneNumberViewModel`), I created a map between both the entity model and the view model and another map between the model entity and the nested property view model. In my controller I just call map between the entity model and the view model!

my mapper keeps failing to transfer to the nested property!

**entity model**,

```
  public class PatientRegistry
    {
        [DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity)]
        [Display(Name = "Record Id")]
        public long RecordId { get; set; }
        [Key, DatabaseGenerated(DatabaseGeneratedOption.None)]
        [Display(Name = "Patient File Number")]
        public long PatientFileId { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(50)]
        [Display(Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        public int CountryCodeId { get; set; }
        public Country CountryCode { get; set; }
        public int CellProvider { get; set; }
        [Required, StringLength(15)]
        public string PatientMobileNo { get; set; }
        [StringLength(20)]
        public string PatientLandLine { get; set; }
}
```

and my **view model** is,

```
public class PatientRegistryViewModel {

        public long PatientFileId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display (Name = "First Name")]
        public string FirstName { get; set; }
        [Required]
        [Display (Name = "Last Name")]
        public string LastName { get; set; }
        public string AliasName { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display (Name = "Date of birth")]
        public DateTime PatientDob { get; set; }

        public MobilePhoneNumberViewModel PatientMobileNo { get; set; }
}
```

my `MobilePhoneNumberViewModel` looks like,

```
  public class MobilePhoneNumberViewModel {

        [Required]
        [Display (Name = "Country Code Id")]
        public int CountryCodeId { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display (Name = "Cell Provider")]
        public int CellProvider { get; set; }

        [Required]
        [Display (Name = "Mobile No")]
        public string PatientMobileNo { get; set; }
    }
```

my maps are,

```
 CreateMap<PatientRegistry, PatientRegistryViewModel> ()
                .ForMember (pr => pr.GenderId, opt => opt.MapFrom (m => m.Gender.Id))
                .ForMember (pr => pr.StatusId, opt => opt.MapFrom (m => m.Status.Id))
                .ForMember (pr => pr.CountryId, opt => opt.MapFrom (m => m.Country.Id))
                .ForMember (pr => pr.StateId, opt => opt.MapFrom (m => m.State.Id))
                .ForMember (pr => pr.CityId, opt => opt.MapFrom (m => m.City.Id))
                .ForMember (pr => pr.NationalityId, opt => opt.MapFrom (m => m.Nationality.Id))
                .ForMember (pr => pr.OccupationId, opt => opt.MapFrom (m => m.Occupation.Id))
                .ForMember (pr => pr.MaritalStatusId, opt => opt.MapFrom (m => m.MaritalStatus.Id))
                .ForMember (dest => dest.PatientMobileNo.PatientMobileNo, opt => opt.MapFrom (src => src.PatientMobileNo))
                .ForMember (pr => pr.PatientMobileNo.CellProvider, opt => opt.MapFrom (m => m.CellProvider))
                .ForMember (pr => pr.PatientMobileNo.CountryCodeId, opt => opt.MapFrom (m => m.CountryCodeId))
                .ForMember (pr => pr.EthnicityId, opt => opt.MapFrom (m => m.Ethnicity.Id))
                .ForMember (pr => pr.Partners, opt => opt.MapFrom (m => m.Partners));
and

     CreateMap<PatientRegistry, MobilePhoneNumberViewModel> ()
                .ForMember (pr => pr.CountryCodeId, opt => opt.MapFrom (m => m.CountryCodeId))
                .ForMember (pr => pr.CellProvider, opt => opt.MapFrom (m => m.CellProvider))
                .ForMember (pr => pr.PatientMobileNo, opt => opt.MapFrom (m => m.PatientMobileNo));
```

(I shortened my models for this question)

I keep getting this error,

> Unhandled Exception: System.Reflection.TargetInvocationException:
>   Exception has been thrown by the target of an invocation. --->
>   System.ArgumentException: Expression 'dest =>
>   dest.PatientMobileNo.PatientMobileNo' must resolve to top-level member
>   and not any child object's properties. Use a custom resolver on the
>   child type or the AfterMap option instead.

if I remove

```
            .ForMember (dest => dest.PatientMobileNo.PatientMobileNo, opt => opt.MapFrom (src => src.PatientMobileNo))
            .ForMember (pr => pr.PatientMobileNo.CellProvider, opt => opt.MapFrom (m => m.CellProvider))
            .ForMember (pr => pr.PatientMobileNo.CountryCodeId, opt => opt.MapFrom (m => m.CountryCodeId))
```

> ```
> AutoMapperMappingException: Error mapping types.
> ```
>
> Mapping types: PatientRegistry -> PatientRegistryViewModel
>   ArtNgCore.Core.Models.ClinicCore.PatientRegistry ->
>   ArtNgCore.Controllers.ViewModels.ClinicCoreViewModels.PatientRegistryViewModel
>
> Type Map configuration: PatientRegistry -> PatientRegistryViewModel
>   ArtNgCore.Core.Models.ClinicCore.PatientRegistry ->
>   ArtNgCore.Controllers.ViewModels.ClinicCoreViewModels.PatientRegistryViewModel
>
> Property: PatientMobileNo

whats going on here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As the exception suggests, you are trying to map from your source object properties to your target object's property's property. Meanwhile, there is no mapping defined for the target object's property itself, `PatientRegistryViewModel.PatientMobileNo`.

```
PatientRegistry.PatientMobileNo → PatientRegistryViewModel.PatientMobileNo.PatientMobileNo 
PatientRegistry.CellProvider → PatientRegistryViewModel.PatientMobileNo.CellProvider
PatientRegistry.CountryCodeId → PatientRegistryViewModel.PatientMobileNo.CellProvider
```

What you can do is to define another mapping from your source object to your target's object' property.

```
cfg.CreateMap<PatientRegistry, PatientRegistryViewModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.PatientMobileNo,opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model));

cfg.CreateMap<PatientRegistry, MobilePhoneNumberViewModel>()
                .ForMember(dest => dest.PatientMobileNo, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.PatientMobileNo))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.CountryCodeId, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.CountryCodeId))
                .ForMember(dest => dest.CellProvider, opt => opt.MapFrom(model => model.CellProvider));
```

Comment: @JSON I am glad to be of help :)

Comment: I was totally ignorant about `opt.MapFrom (model => model))` where can I find it in the docs?

Comment: @JSON please have a look at http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Projection.html?highlight=MapFrom%20